# Templates instantiation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I am confused by how C++ instantiate template. I have a piece of code:

```
template <class T, int arraySize>
void test1(T (&array)[arraySize])
{
    cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
}

template<class T>
void test2(T &array)
{
    cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int abc[5];
    test1(abc);
    test2(abc);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are my questions:
**1. How does the size of array abc is passed to test1 (the parameter arraySize )? 

2. How does C++ compiler determine the type of T in the two templates?**

Comment: You mean something like `test1<int, 5>(abc)`? The second one doesn't make sense at all. You have a function `test2<T>` and you are indexing it as if it was an array?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In test1 the compiler creates a template with T[arraySize] being its form.
When you call test1(abc) you are providing an input argument of type int[5] which the template matcher automatically matches.

However, if you were to write

```
int n=10;
int *abc = new int[n];
test1(abc);
test1<int,n>(abc);
```

then the compilation would fail and the compiler would claim that it has no template matching the test1(abc) function call or the test1< int,n >(abc) function call.

This is because the size of abc is now dynamically allocated and so the type of abc is a pointer which has a different type and hence no template could be matched to the above two calls.

The following code shows you some types

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> void printName() {cout<<typeid(T).name()<<endl;}

int main()
{      
    printName<int[2]>();  //type = A2_i
    printName<int*>();     //type = Pi

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: besides, that `abc[n]` won't compile anyway, because C++ doesn't support dynamically sized arrays (not even C++11, as far as I know). I guess you have a C99 background?

Comment: It compiled fine under apples llvm compiler 3.0 though. Have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7):

1. There is no parameter passing in the normal sense, since template parameters are resolved at compile time.
2. Both `arraySize` and `T` are inferred from the type of the `array` parameter. Since you pass an `int[5]`, `arraySize` and `T` become `5` and `int`, respectively, at compile time.

If, for example, you declared `int* abc = new int[5];`, your compiler would barf at the point you try to call `test1(abc)`. Apart from a basic type-mismatch, `int*` doesn't carry enough information to infer the size of the array.

Answer (score 5):

It is called *template argument deduction*.

The *type* of `abc` at call-site is : `int(&)[5]` which has two info combined: `int` and `5`. And the function template accepts argument of type `T(&)[N]`, but the argument at call-site is, `int(&)[5]`, so the compiler deduces that `T` is `int` and `N` is `5`.

Read these:

- [The C++ Template Argument Deduction](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/409) (at ACCU)
- [Template argument deduction (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftemplate_argument_deduction.htm) (at IBM)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also add to what Nawaz says: the theory is [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).